# How can I append a string to an object property?

Tags: php

I am trying to send a response back to my front end with the amount of days in a customers billing period. I query this number but would like to append `" Days"` after it. So far I have:

```
<?php
require "../../inc/dbinfo.inc";

$projectnum =$_POST['projectnum'];

$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT (SELECT TermsofPayment FROM tblCustomers WHERE CUSTOMERID = ProjectCustomer) AS NetTerms FROM tblProjects WHERE PROJECTNOID = ?");

if($sql){
  $sql->bind_param("i", $projectnum);
  $sql->execute();
  $hold = $sql->get_result();
  $obj = $hold->fetch_assoc();
  $addOn = " Days";
  $obj->NetTerms = $obj->{'NetTerms'. $addOn};

  echo json_encode($obj);
}
$sql->close();
exit();

?>
```

After trial and error it appears as though the second last line has no effect on the result. I've looked through the web to find no solutions to this (maybe my search didn't contain the right keywords).

Current Response: `{"NetTerms":30}`

Desired Response: `{"NetTerms":30 Days}`

Comment: You are trying to *access* a property called `NetTermsDays`. You probably just want `$obj->NetTerms . $addOn`?

Comment: `$obj->NetTerms = "{$obj->NetTerms} $addOn";`

Comment: It looks like `$addOn` is actually empty, even though you show it being defined in the first code block. Otherwise I think you'd be setting `$obj->NetTerms` to null, because `$obj{'NetTerms Days'}` is nonexistent.

Comment: @Don'tPanic when I swap $obj for $addOn in the echo statement I do get " Days" as the response though

Comment: @deceze I tried with no luck. is there anything I need to change in the echo statement?

Comment: @AbraCadaver I can't get this to work either. Would I need to adjust my echo statement for the edit you made?

Comment: You want to append `$addOn` to the value of `$obj->NetTerms` if I understand you right. Then do: `$obj->NetTerms .= $addOn; ` What @deceze said is not appending it but concatenating it.

Comment: @jrswgtr yes this is what I want. should the other do the same though? I can't get this to work either , I'll update my post to show all my work.

Comment: deceze's and jrswgtr's proposals are practical the same. Just another syntax.

Comment: @Jordan are you sure that `$obj->NetTerms` is a public property?

Comment: @jrswgtr I'm not too familiar with PHP OOP wise. How would I instantiate this or check for this?

Comment: I see that you spell `$addon` now instead of `$addOn` is that on purpose?

Comment: To check if a property is public do `var_dump( $obj);`

Comment: @jrswgtr just a typo, the problem still persists.

Comment: doesn't `fetch_assoc()` return an array instead of an object?? So it would be `$obj['NetTerms'] .= $addon;` or `$obj['NetTerms'] = $obj['NetTerms'] . $addon;`

Comment: If you don't understand it well do `var_dump($obj)` and post the results.

Comment: @Jeff that was the problem! I thought objects and arrays essentially worked the same though?

Comment: @Jordan - sometimes, yes, but not essentially... So this solved it?

Comment: @Jeff yes, that was the solution, I will accept the solution if you post it as an answer

Comment: _sidenote_ for @Jordan: please don't change the question's crucial code parts from comment's infos. Now 90% of the comments don't make sense anymore.

Comment: @Jeff corrected, thanks for the notice

Comment: next time please make sure you got `error_reporting()` on, this would have helped to get the issue earlier!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have/had two problems there:

1st you wanted to concatenate a variable to another one and had a wrong syntax.

```
$addOn = " Days";
$obj->NetTerms = $obj->{'NetTerms' .$addOn};
// this would try to get a value of `$obj->NetTerms Days`, which doesn't exist.
```

should have been

```
$obj->NetTerms = $obj->NetTerms . $addOn;
// or 
$obj->NetTerms .= $addOn;
```

All of this threw an error, because `$obj` is an array (as return from `fetch_assoc()`), not an object. 
So treat it as an array and it should work:

```
$obj['NetTerms'] = $obj['NetTerms'] . $addon;
```